# UIScrollView in NavigationController ignores top layout guide

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I've seen similar questions about custom transitions([iOS7 Custom ViewController transition and Top Layout Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789205/ios7-custom-viewcontroller-transition-and-top-layout-guide) and [Navigation controller top layout guide not honored with custom transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312765/navigation-controller-top-layout-guide-not-honored-with-custom-transition)), but I have problem even with regular push. I'm using latest Xcode available now (Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)).

Here is my storyboard:
[image: storyboard]
Problem occurs in 3rd VC

Here is 3rd VC settings:
[image]

My 3rd controller's layout is follows:

```
UIView
 UIScrollView
  InnerUIView
    Other views
```

I've tried two different ways to create a layout:

**Ignore top layout guide (it has y = 64 because of nav bar)**

I pinned scrollview's top to container (ignoring topLayoutGuide), manually set height of inner view and pinned its top to scrollView. It gave me the following result:
[image]

Looks fine, but why do I need top layout guide then?

**Use topLayout guide**

ScrollView's top is pinned to topLayoutGuide. 
[image]

As you can see, top button moved down and view looks strange.

What is the right way of creating such layouts?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and spent hours pulling my hair out. 
My container view inside scrollview had weird top offset despite the fact that it had top constraint set.
The workaround I've found - you have to uncheck `Adjust Scroll View Insets` in your controller layout options

[image]

that way content view (in my case) stays pinned to scrollview's top.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any reasonable explanation of this behaviour.

Comment: Where exactly is this Layout section hiding?

Comment: Its in the Attribute Inspector when storyboard/xib controller object is selected.

Comment: Thank you, had come across this fix before but had forgotten it. I was expecting too much from iOS to do the logical thing and only adjust insets when the scrollview is actually overlapping the area outside the layout guides, instead of adding a fixed offset as it seems to currently do. (I do the logical thing when adjust insets when a keyboard overlaps the scrollview for example). Wasted so much time trying to debug my code, when it should've been iOS's faults I should have invesigated first

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Xcode 7 and 8, I had to **uncheck** the 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' for the Views in my Navigation View Controller. And yes, it wasted too much time before I figured this out.

EDIT: Apple has found out that we have found a solution, so they managed to break this again in XCode 9 and 10, to keep us developers pulling our hair. Haven't found a solution yet.

[image]